# Verifying DO-178B/C compliance in C++

Tags: c++, testing, verification

It has been asked [before](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/what-programming-languages-are-used-for-equipment-onboard-aircraft) what programming languages are used in avionics programming, the main ones being C, Ada as well as C++ in adherence with DO-178B/C.

To be more specific, I will focus my question on C++, when I ask: what concrete methods are used to verify software for compliance with DO-178B/C?

I have found lots of details as to what DO-178B/C requires one to verify but not how it is concretely achieved in practice.

As I understand, the op-code itself is analysed, not just the source?

Comment: TO THE CLOSE VOTE: I have removed “tools” and focused the question on “methods” only, so the answer should outline an approach rather than simply list tools.

Comment: In general, code coverage, static analysis and {proof of} unit testing.  Also, performance (timing) and robustness also.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What do you mean by “proof of”? Do you mean formal proofing like with Coq?

Comment: I define "proof" as documentation that the process was followed.  For example, the output from a code coverage tool, the output of a static analysis tool, screen snapshots from a debugger, screen snapshots from an oscilloscope.  In general, the governmental agencies say that if "it" is not documented, "it" didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question would be more about the challenges when verifying OOT code per DO-178. This doc presents a detail explanation of the potential structural coverage issues pertaining to each fundamental features of OOT. It provides suggestions of appropriate verification approaches and can be found [here](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/air_software/cast/cast_papers/media/cast-4.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

DO-178B/C is not a "coding standard", therefore you can't verify that software is compliant with it. DO-178B/C is a guideline that specifies the way how should be the software developed and what artifacts should be created during the whole software development life cycle in order to achieve required criticality and to be "certifiable". During the certification, an authority such as FAA or EASA will verify the compliance of software plans, software development, and verification processes, software verification results with DO-178B/C.

DO-178C and the supplementing document DO-332 defines some restrictions on usage of Object-Oriented programming, which may be understood as an allowed subset of C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

[PerForce](https://www.perforce.com/) is a top powerful framework for developing software according to DO-178 standards. [this](https://www.perforce.com/blog/alm/best-practices-do-178c-compliance)  post completely explains what do you need in DO-178 standards, and PerForce what to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

[RapiTest](https://www.rapitasystems.com/products/rapitest) also helps  produce evidence for DO-178 and also ISO 26262 certification.

*Disclosure: I am not associated with the company behind RapiTest.*